# Why doesn't animation render in Cycles work when everything is played in EEVEE?

Tags: rendering, animation, cycles-render-engine

I recently started learning Blender, made a little animation.

By pressing the spacebar, the animation is played, I made the first trial animation in EEVEE frame by frame, everything works, and then I decided to make the final animation in Cycles, but when rendering in Cycles, I just have the first frame displayed without animation.

I tried to change the scene, changed the Word Output from All to Cycles in the shaders, reinstalled Blender and tried to repeat even in older versions and nothing worked.

In the end I tried to make the new simplest animation like a sphere rolls along the x axis and tried to render the animation in Cycles but even that didn't work.

Have you experienced this or just have an idea what could have happened?

[image]

Comment: Would you mind showing us a screenshot of the render settings? And how you start the render, with F12 or Ctrl+F12? Or using the menu?

Comment: You should describe in detail what steps you take to render the animation. Clearly you do something wrong when trying to render, but without knowing what you do exactly, it's impossible to know what that is. There doesn't seem to be any obvious problems with your scene judging from the sceenshot so hitting Ctrl + F12 should start rendering the animation. It will take considerably more time than EEVEE(might be a few minutes per frame so with 170 frames it might take 5-10 hours to render) and animation will be saved according to your output settings.

Comment: @GordonBrinkmann Hi! I used the menu. 
Photo Cycles Render Devices 
https://drive.google.com/file/d/15BVSAuxBEv0GpqrDidQc775u4ixlUdEx/view?usp=sharing

Comment: @MartynasŽiemys Hello!
1. I'm on the Animation tab in the Material Preview mode, I play the animation by pressing the spacebar. 

2. I check that Cycles --> Supported --> GPU Compute is turn on in Render Properties (I read this earlier that it will render faster this way, but I tried something else - nothing has changed).

3. I reduced the number of Samples by 512 and unchecked the Noise Threshold.

Comment: @MartynasŽiemys 
4. I went to the Output Properties tab and set 24 fps, frame start 1 - end 170.
5. I chose where to save the file, in PNG format and the rest left everything else as it was.
6. After that, in the top menu, I click animation rendering and just a picture without animation is rendered. If at the first stages I choose EEVEE, then everything works fine.

Comment: Now that's a bit unclear, because there is nothing called "Animation rendering" in the Topbar. There is a Render menu and there is Render Animation choice in it that you should click. Is that what you meant? The UI will show frames rendering one at a time. Are you sure you wait long enough for the first frame to render completely so the second one can start rendering?

Comment: @MartynasŽiemys Yes, I meant it. And I wait until the end of the render, which by the way starts anew sometimes, not every time. I check the folder where it should have been saved, but it is empty. If I do the same steps but in EEVEE, then everything turns out right.

Comment: I have never seen a problem like that before. From one of your screenshots, I guess you might be using Linux, is that so? What is the OS you use?Maybe file system permission issue could cause something like this?..

Comment: @MartynasŽiemys I'm using Windows 11, but I tried to do the same on a MacOS and the problem recurred. Since I did these steps even with primitive animation, for example, the sphere rolls along the x axis and the problem repeated. I think I'm doing something wrong, but I can’t understand what exactly... I have already watched and repeated a lot of the videos on YouTube, always the same and doesn't work.

Answer (score 0):

Let's try a very simple workflow that works with rendering an animation.

1. I reset Blender to factory settings, going to File -> Defaults -> Load Factory Settings.
2. I keyframe the default cube by selecting it and hitting <kbd>i</kbd> while hovering over the 3d viewport. I choose Location. I can see it worked because the location input fields change color.

[image]

3. I set another frame in the Timeline, move the cube a bit(with <kbd>g</kbd>) and keyframe it again the exact same way as before. I also hit <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>End</kbd> while hovering over timeline to set current frame to last one to limit my animation to 10 frames so I don't have to wait long for it to render.

[image]

4. I go to User Preferences by hitting <kbd>F4</kbd>-><kbd>P</kbd> and set up GPU render device in the System tab while simultaneously being slightly ashamed of the terribly outdated hardware in my home computer.

[image]

5. I go to Render tab and set some low quality render settings so it renders extremely fast:

[image]

6. Then the Output settings:

[image]

7. I hit <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>F12</kbd>:

[image]

That's it. The animation is rendered to my output folder:

[image]

Comment: Yes! It works! I'm very grateful to you!